# How to remove element from list without using for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two list of tuples,`A` and `B`, that stores the pairs of data ids, and I want to remove pairs from `A` if the pair `(x,y)` or `(y,x)` in `B` are also in `A`.

I tried to do it by using for loop like below,

```
A = [(321, 33), (56, 991), (645, 2), (8876, 556)]
B = [(33, 321), (645, 2)]

for pair in B:
    if pair in A: 
        A.remove(pair)
    elif (pair[1], pair[0]) in A:
        A.remove((pair[1], pair[0]))

print(A)  # [(56, 991), (8876, 556)]
```

but when the elements in list is large, this code runs very slowly.

So I want to make this code faster, possibly avoid using for loops or completely different way.
Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: 0) dont user remove. You are iterating over the whole list everytime trying to match the value to remove. Iterate over your list using an index value; 1) which list is larger, A or B? currently you are iterating over B once and over A multiple times (len(B) times); 2) can you make A sorted, somehow? 3) Dont

Comment: Sounds like it might make more sense for you to be using sets instead of lists in the first place; and possibly frozensets instead of tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `A` has unique items, you can convert both lists to sets and use set difference, with the caveat that you add the reversed tuples into the `B_set`:

```
set_B = set(B).union([(j,i) for (i,j) in B])
out = list(set(A) - set_B)
```

Output:

```
[(321, 33), (645, 2)]
```

If `A` doesn't have unique items and you want to keep duplicate items, you can use list comprehension for the second line instead:

```
set_B = set(B).union([(j,i) for (i,j) in B])
out = [tpl for tpl in A if tpl in set_B]
```

Comment: @AppleBS I mean the real performance will show for large lists. I ran my solution and OP's solution for len(A)=1000, len(B)=100 lists and my solution is 58 times faster at 159us vs 9.39 ms.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing, create a new list by excluding the common elements:

```
[(x,y) for x,y in A if (x,y) not in B and (y,x) not in B]
```

Output:

> [(56, 991), (8876, 556)]

Comment: [(x, y) for x, y in A if (x, y) not in B and (y, x) not in B]

Comment: I ran a simple benchmark of your code vs kalcium's code. Your code is significantly slower at 145ms vs 101ms when looped 100000 times.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you use sets instead of lists and that the second set contains both variants of elements (`(x, y)` and `(x, y)`)…

```py
A = {(321, 33), (56, 991), (645, 2), (8876, 556)}
B = {(33, 321), (645, 2), (321, 33), (2, 645)}
```

You only need a set subtraction:

```py
print(A - B)
```